# Odds Ratio and Confidence Limit for Fisher test in SAS

Tags: sas, statistics

Is there a way in SAS to generate Odds ratio and Confidence Interval for Fisher? I know, we can find CI, OR for Pearson's Chi-square. Even P-value is available for Pearson's chi-square and Fisher using proc freq. I have tried FISHER/EXACT statistics but OR and CI are not available for Fisher. Please help!

Comment: Do you have a reference on how that would be calculated?

Comment: It should be calculated with 95% confidence interval, I am looking for a built in procedure In SAS for Fisher's calculations because I am new to stats. I am getting slightly different P-values for Pearson chi-square and Fisher, so there should be different confidence Intervals as well, depending the relation between p-value and CI

Comment: I get that, can you point me to a formula reference or example where that's done? Not SAS specific, in general statistical view.

Comment: there is a basic doc - http://www.biochemia-medica.com/content/odds-ratio-calculation-usage-and-interpretation

Comment: Notice a single formula for SE.